# Hot keys forcing Siri to open twice

Tags: applescript, macos, siri

About 30% of the time when pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for a fraction of a second too long, it causes *Siri* to close and open again. This delays the process a significant amount that at times its required to be clicked just to even listen.
*Console: Errors & Warnings*[image] It seems that the highlighted error is whats causing this. Im not too familiar with AppleScript, I did try `sudo killall` for the associated processes but the issue is still persistent.

Comment: how did you get the console: error and warnigns, if I may ask?